# Assign map (coordinates) to modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to assign a map (a clickable area) to a modal, so that it works like a button. I enclose my code. As you can see I have a picture with a map that I would like to link to the modal further down... there is also a button linked to the modal and that works properly. I hope you see what I mean.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<a href="http://s621.photobucket.com/user/viktorvnh/media/deskone_zpswpfj5mrc.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i621.photobucket.com/albums/tt296/viktorvnh/deskone_zpswpfj5mrc.jpg" alt=" photo deskone_zpswpfj5mrc.jpg" usemap="#Map" border="0"/>
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="374,414,624,570" href="#" />
</map>
</a>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Det här är innehållet</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        DET HÄR ÄR OCKSÅ INNEHÅLLET<a href="http://s621.photobucket.com/user/viktorvnh/media/deskone_zpswpfj5mrc.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i621.photobucket.com/albums/tt296/viktorvnh/deskone_zpswpfj5mrc.jpg" alt=" photo deskone_zpswpfj5mrc.jpg" width="540" height="358" border="0"/>
</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you have already attached code, you'd better attach a link to codepen containing it to let people easily see result, edit and help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to init modal on your area and remove href from  wraping map

```
<a>
    <img src="http://i621.photobucket.com/albums/tt296/viktorvnh/deskone_zpswpfj5mrc.jpg" usemap="#Map"/>
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
         <area shape="rect" coords="374,414,624,570" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>
    </map>
</a>
```